# String Objects or primitive strings..?

Tags: javascript

i am a newbie to Js.
I am reading an book and it says that a string object created like this
var `stringObj = new String();` contains string methods like .`topUpperCase` etc..
but i see that primitive string also contains that..

eg.

```
var primitive = 'Hello';
console.log(primitive.toUpperCase());
var stringObj = new String();
stringObj = "halo";
console.log(stringObj.toUpperCase());
```

So why is this? i mean is this because of the wrapper objects on primitives..
And is there any use of creating string Obect.
thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan  Thanks so well identically they are the same thing. i mean creating a primitive or an object right?

Comment: Note: The line `stringObj = "halo";` actually discards the object by reassigning `stringObj`. So, both `console.log()` statements are using primitive values. To create a string object with a value, the value should be provided as an argument to the constructor – `var stringObj = new String("halo");`.

Comment: This is known as autoboxing. Primitives get implicitly "objectified" so you can access their prototypes without adding unnecessary "noise" to your code. To autobox a number, wrap it in parentheses.  Ex: `(2).toFixed` This is so there is no ambiguity with decimal syntax.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini They aren't precisely the same. The [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for the values will be different – `'string'` for the primitive vs. `'object'` for the `new String`. And, when comparing objects, two different instances are never equal, regardless of the similarity in values they may hold – `new String("") === new String("") // false` vs `"" === "" // true`.